# How to extract text of this class and do additions on it

Tags: jquery

On Click of a plus icon , i need to extract the text present under some  div with  class name as  sellprice

(so that later i can do this update it with the quantity present (sellprice * quantity)

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5axh3xzs/23/

I have got two issue here

1. Unable to extract the sellprice text .
2. how can i do parseFloat on sellprice as it as got special symbol also with in it ??

I tried as

```
$(document).on('click', '.icon-plus', function (e) {
var value = parseInt($(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val());
    $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val(value+1);

var sellprice =  $(this).closest('div').find('.Itm_right_aside.sellprice ').text();

    alert(sellprice);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this with `replace()`, `\D` which is a shorthand character class that matches all non-digits:

```
var sellprice =  $(this).closest('.lastItm_Wrap')
                 .find('.Itm_right_aside .sellprice').text().replace(/[^\d.]/g,'');

// output 188
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5axh3xzs/25/)**

Comment: this one looks simple and more clear , thanks for your time .

Comment: This solution has a bug, what if there is decimal number! For example : 12.05 or 12,05 it will return 1205 as price!!!

Comment: @loncar thanks to point out, for float value i have inserted `.` in regex and if want to fetch value with `,` then simply add `,` in regex.

Answer (score 2):

try this in your fiddle :

```
var sellprice =  $(this).closest('.lastItm_Wrap').find('.sellprice').text();

alert(sellprice);
```

To get price use `substring` before `parseFloat`.

substring example :

```
alert('price : ' + parseFloat(sellprice.substring(1)));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0ojo8hm9/

**EDIT** : in one line (as a text) :

```
var sellprice =  $(this).closest('.lastItm_Wrap').find('.sellprice').text().substring(1);
```

you turn it to float (`parseFloat`) if you are using that to do some math calculation :)

Comment: @Kiran glad I can help, there is a bug with accepted answer take look at my comment there.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using jquery [**parents**()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/):

```
var sellprice = $(this).parents("div.lastItm_Wrap").find(".Itm_right_aside .sellprice").text();
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.icon-minus', function(e) {
  var value = parseInt($(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val());
  if (value >= 1) {
    $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val(value - 1);
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '.icon-plus', function(e) {
  var value = parseInt($(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val());
  $(this).closest('div').find('.QtyInput').val(value + 1);

  var sellprice = $(this).parents("div.lastItm_Wrap").find(".Itm_right_aside .sellprice").text();

  alert(sellprice);

});
```

```css
.pageMidLogo {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
.createAccountWrap {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.createAccountWrap .h3_head {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 25px !important;
}
.iLabel {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.insideInput {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.tooltipIcon {
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 16px;
  background: #ababab;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
.tooltipIcon:before {
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  color: #fff;
}
.pop_tooltipIcon {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #d03e43;
}
.iconPinReload {
  /*background: url(../images/icon-capthareload.png) 10px 10px no-repeat #f6f6f6;
 border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
 width: 52px;
 height: 41px;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
}
/*.iconPinReload:hover{
 background: url(../images/icon-capthareload.png) 10px 10px no-repeat #f0f0f0;
}*/

.tpMenuWrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 88%;
}
.btMenuWrap {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 88%;
}
.ul_menu {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
.ul_menu li {
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.ul_menu li a {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #ddd;
}
.ul_menu li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.panelCloseBtn {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #777 !important;
}
.panelCloseBtn:hover {
  color: #999 !important;
}
.homeListMenuWrap {
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li {
  padding: 25px 25px 20px 25px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li a:hover {
  color: #d03e43;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li .qrcode {
  background: url(../images/icon-QRcode.png) left top no-repeat;
  padding-left: 120px;
  display: block;
  color: #314158;
  min-height: 110px;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li .homedeliver {
  background: url(../images/icon-homedelivery.png) left top no-repeat;
  padding-left: 120px;
  display: block;
  color: #314158;
  min-height: 110px;
}
.homeListMenuWrap li .qrcode p,
.homeListMenuWrap li .homedeliver p {
  font-size: 15px;
}
.qrcode_errorWrap {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.qrcode_errorWrap .qrcodeError {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 26px !important;
  margin-bottom: 25px !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
}
.orDivider {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px !important;
  font-style: italic;
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.orDivider span {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.orDivider .hr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
/* Tree Menu Start */

.TreeMenu {
  width: 100%;
}
.TreeMenu .ui-collapsible-heading {
  margin: 0px !important;
}
.TreeMenu .ui-collapsible-heading a {
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
.TreeMenu .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.TreeMenu .ui-collapsible-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  border: 0px !important;
  background: #fff;
}
.TreeMenu_Content {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_left_aside {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl {
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl .vegLabel {
  background: url(../images/veg_labels.png) left 3px no-repeat;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl .nonvegLabel {
  background: url(../images/nonveg_labels.png) left 3px no-repeat;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 50px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl h3 .prdDiscription {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 1px;
  width: auto !important;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_dtsl .addonsList {
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_img {
  width: 74px;
  height: 74px;
  float: left;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_img img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside .trashBtn {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside p {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside p strike {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap .Itm_right_aside p b {
  font-weight: 600;
}
/* Tree Child */

.TreeMenuChild .ui-collapsible-content {
  padding: 0px;
}
.TreeMenuChild .ui-icon-plus:after {
  background-image: url(images/icons-png/carat-r-black.png) !important;
}
.TreeMenuChild .ui-icon-minus:after {
  background-image: url(images/icons-png/carat-d-white.png) !important;
  background-color: #d03e43;
}
.TreeMenuChild .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.TreeMenuChild .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle:last-child {
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.addonsBtn {
  width: auto !important;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px !important;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.addonsBtn a {
  color: #333 !important;
}
.Itm_discrp {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.Itm_discrp h3 {
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
  padding: 0px;
}
.Itm_discrp p {
  text-align: justify;
}
.Qty_Wrap {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.Qty_Wrap .QtyBtn {
  float: left;
  width: 33px;
  border-radius: 34px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.Qty_Wrap .QtyBtn:before {
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.Qty_Wrap .ui-input-text {
  float: left;
  border: 0px;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: #fff;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.Qty_Wrap .QtyInput {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 1.6em;
}
.addonsContent h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.addonsContent .rightAction {
  float: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: -28px;
}
.addonsContent .rightAction a {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.addonsContent .rightAction a.tick {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.addonsContent .rightAction a.remove {
  color: #333;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap ul {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap ul li:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
.addonsContent .addonsQtyWrap ul li.active {
  border: 1px solid #d03e43;
  color: #d03e43;
}
.addonsContent .popup_content_addonsWrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap {
  width: 100%;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul li form {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: auto;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul li .ui-mini {
  margin: 0px;
}
.addonsContent .addonsListWrap ul li .ui-mini label {
  background: #fff !important;
  border: 0px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(208, 62, 67, 0.9);
  border-top: 2px solid #d03e43;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer:hover {
  background: rgba(208, 62, 67, 1);
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner:after {
  content: '\e988';
  font-family: "fontello";
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 37px;
  position: absolute;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .myorders,
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal {
  float: left;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .myorders {
  padding: 12px 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .myorders i {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 120px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal {
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal b {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal b span {
  font-size: 22px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_inner .subtotal .minOrder {
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
/*.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_right{
 width:85%;
 float:left;
 padding-left: 12px;
}*/

/*.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_right .subtotal{
 font-size:18px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_right .subtotal span{
 margin-left:10px;
 font-size:24px;
}
.myOrderPanel_footer .myOrderPanel_right .subtotal i{
 width:100%;
 float:left;
 font-size:13px;
 font-style:normal;
}*/

/* My Order page start */

.MyOrdersPage {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
}
.MyOrdersPage .TreeMenu_Content .lastItm_Wrap {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.vendorNameDtsl {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.vendorNameDtsl h6 {
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding-top: 4px !important;
}
.vendorNameDtsl span {
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
  padding: 2px 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.orderSummary_priceDtsl {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.orderSummary_priceDtsl li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.orderSummary_priceDtsl li span {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}
.orderSummary_priceDtsl li.totalsection {
  padding-top: 17px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #d03e43;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
/*.orderSummary_priceDtsl .inclusiveTax{
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 margin:30px 0px !important;
}*/

.customerNameDtl {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.customerNameDtl_left {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 26px;
  width: auto;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
.customerNameDtl_right {
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  text-align: right;
}
.customerNameDtl_right .totalsection {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  color: #d03e43;
}
.customerNameDtl_right .totalsection span {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.customerNameDtl_right button {
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
}
/* My Order page end */

.placeorderimg {
  width: 176px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.cancelOrder {
  width: 100% !important;
  float: left;
  padding: 18px 0px !important;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.commentWrap {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  margin: 15px 0px;
}
.commentWrap textarea {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 15px 0px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-a" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="TreeMenu_Content" id="itemcontent703">
    <div class="lastItm_Wrap">
      <div class="Itm_left_aside">
        <div class="Itm_dtsl">
          <h3>Item1<button style="display:none;" class="btn-d icon-ellipsis prdDiscription ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button></h3>

          <div class="Qty_Wrap">
            <button class="btn-d icon-minus QtyBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">-</button>
            <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
              <input type="text" class="QtyInput" value="0">
            </div>
            <button class="btn-d icon-plus QtyBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">+</button>
          </div>
          <div style="display:none;" class="Itm_discrp">
            <h3>Item1</h3>

            <p></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Itm_right_aside">
        <p style="display:none;"><strike class="cutoff">₹ 12</strike>  <b class="discclass">0 Rs off</b>
        </p>
        <p><b class="sellprice">₹ 12</b>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="addonsWrap-placeholder">
      <!-- placeholder for addonsWrap -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="TreeMenu_Content" id="itemcontent693">
    <div class="lastItm_Wrap">
      <div class="Itm_left_aside">
        <div class="Itm_dtsl">
          <h3>Item2<button style="display:none;" class="btn-d icon-ellipsis prdDiscription ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all"></button></h3>

          <div class="Qty_Wrap">
            <button class="btn-d icon-minus QtyBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">-</button>
            <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
              <input type="text" class="QtyInput" value="0">
            </div>
            <button class="btn-d icon-plus QtyBtn ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">+</button>
          </div>
          <div style="display:none;" class="Itm_discrp">
            <h3>Item2</h3>

            <p>toppings and crustings toppings and crustings toppings and crustings toppin</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Itm_right_aside">
        <p style="display:block;"><strike class="cutoff">₹ 200</strike>  <b class="discclass">12 Rs off</b>
        </p>
        <p><b class="sellprice">₹ 188</b>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display: none;" id="addonsWrap-placeholder">
      <!-- placeholder for addonsWrap -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```